# Dataflow Programming API for Java?

Tags: java, concurrency, multicore, dataflow

I am looking for a Dataflow / Concurrent Programming API for Java.
I know there's [DataRush](http://www.pervasivedatarush.com/), but it's not free. What I'm interested in specifically is multicore data processing, and not distributed, which rules out [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) or [Hadoop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadoop).
Any thoughts?
Thanks,
Rollo

Comment: [Akka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/1.3.1/java/dataflow.html) has dataflow capabilities.

Answer (score 7):

You might try [gpars](http://www.gpars.org/); it apparently has implementations of data flow variables and streams in Java even though it is geared towards providing concurrent programming goodies for Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Might try the upcoming fork/join library which will (hopefully) be in Java 7 as part of the JSR 166y update.

Main project page:
- http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/index.html

Pointers to lots of links about what it is:
 - http://tech.puredanger.com/java7#jsr166

Answer (score 0):

Does the built in Java [concurrent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package meet your needs?  It's a very nice package, built in ThreadPools, CopyOnWriteCollections, Executors, Future.  We use it to process large volumns of data in thread pools.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/rfqu/df4j is simple but powerful dataflow library. If it lacks some desired features, they can be added easly. It can exploit java.concurrent.ExecutorService.